# Ranksums returns repeated pvalues

Tags: python, bioinformatics, p-value, scipy.stats

[image]

I'm trying to create a volcano plots using metabolomics data. Pvalues were obtained using scipy.stats ranksums function. It appears pvalues are repeated or rounded.
My dataframe contains lo2fc values and I'm trying to add pvalues calculated in this way:

```
from scipy.stats import ranksums
groupA = subset_filter.iloc[:,4:7].values
groupB = subset_filter.iloc[:,7:10].values


# #Wilcoxon test using ranksums function 
test = ranksums(groupA1,groupB2, axis=1)
```

Which is suppose to calculate over all rows (12k+) on those groups. Even though values are different it's giving me repeated pvalue values.

Answer (score 0):

`ranksums(groupA1, groupB2, axis=1)` will perform the `ranksums` test over corresonding rows of `groupA1` and `groupB2` if `groupA1` and `groupB2` are 2D.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
rng = np.random.default_rng(8542454925621)
x = rng.random(size=(4, 10))
y = rng.random(size=(4, 15))

res = stats.ranksums(x, y, axis=1).pvalue
ref = [stats.ranksums(xi, yi).pvalue for xi, yi in zip(x, y)]
np.testing.assert_allclose(res, ref)  # passes
```

If the function is producing repeated p-values, it is unlikely that it is because the function is misbehaving. Note that the ranksums statistic is based on ranks of observations, not the values themselves, so if the samples have only a few observations, there will only be a handful of unique statistic values and therefore only a handful of unique p-values.

```py
x = rng.random(size=(1000, 10))
y = rng.random(size=(1000, 15))
p = stats.ranksums(x, y, axis=1).pvalue
len(np.unique(p))  # 54
```